# Visual basic: Adding a margin to the webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using a the Webbrowser in VB and I've been trying to add a margin to the top of the page. I simply need the 20-30px header on the page I navigate to, removed.

I tested the settings on the properties window, after selecting the webbrowser but it didn't work (unless I did something wrong)

Is there a way to do this programmatically with vb code or possibly using css/html which is fixed on to all pages, so that it display the margin?

Here is a visual example on an image I've created:
http://s9.postimg.org/t7gqe5exb/webbrowser_example.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, is monitor when the web browser finishes loading a page, and then inject a javascript code into the page which will adjust the margin:

```
Imports System.IO

'add a reference to the COM object "Microsoft HTML Object Library" for this
Imports mshtml

Public Class Form4
    'execute a code every time the webBrowser finishes loading a page
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        'find the head element of the loaded page
        Dim headElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
        'create a script element
        Dim scriptElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")
        Dim element As IHTMLScriptElement = DirectCast(scriptElement.DomElement, IHTMLScriptElement)
        'write the actual script to the script element 
        element.text = "function adjustMargin() {document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style['margin-top']='-40px';}"
        'append our new script element back to the head element of the page
        headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement)
        'call the function from our new script
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("adjustMargin")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form4_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```